# How to convert a MS Office DOC/XLS/PPT & PDF to image on Android

Tags: android, ms-office, openoffice.org, libreoffice

We need to be able to import Office documents as images into an app. On Windows we use LibreOffice which has a command line --convert flag.

Now we need to do the same for Android and iOS.

LibreOffice is not ready for Android yet.
Open Office for Android (AdrOpen Office) is there, but it does not have the --convert line option

One possibility I am looking at is to use JodConverter, but the solution needs to work offline - my reading of JodConverter is that it "uses openeoffice.org", and I'm not if this means it accesses the web site when doing the conversion, or it simply requires some software components from openoffice.org to be installed locally.

Note I am not asking how to open the documents, but how to convert them to an image, which we then import as a background in our app. We do not need to "live edit" them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **PDF2JPG** app to convert PDF to jpg. This app is available on google playstore freely. for doc to jpg conversion , you need to use the combination of two apps. First you need to use **Doc To Pdf** app from playstore for convert it to PDF, which is freely available on google playstore then convert PDF to jpg.